# How to capitalize every word in a string in cases where title() doesn't 100% work out in python

Tags: python-3.x

**Hi, 
I am relatively new to python, and I was wondering why the code below doesn't remain applicable to all of the sample tests in Codewars ("Jaden Casing strings") which is as follows:**

**Jaden Casing Strings:**
Jaden Smith, the son of Will Smith, is the star of films such as The Karate Kid (2010) and After Earth (2013). Jaden is also known for some of his philosophy that he delivers via Twitter. When writing on Twitter, he is known for almost always capitalizing every word. For simplicity, you'll have to capitalize each word, check out how contractions are expected to be in the example below.

Your task is to convert strings to how they would be written by Jaden Smith. The strings are actual quotes from Jaden Smith, but they are not capitalized in the same way he originally typed them.

Example:

Not Jaden-Cased: "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
Jaden-Cased:     "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"
Link to Jaden's former Twitter account @officialjaden via archive.org

**My code:**

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    for word in string:
        if "'" in word:
            word.capitalize()
        else:
            word.title()
    return string
```

Comment: How does your code fail? (Don't answer in a comment; this is supposed to go into your question.)

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to Python I tired below method which seems to work:

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    return ' '.join(i.capitalize() for i in string.split())
```

I was trying to use .title() in different ways but couldn't seem get solution with that but i could split string and capitalize every word.